# Using EventBridge to Monitory Lambda Failures

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-event-bridge

I currently monitor my AWS Glue Jobs and Crawlers using EventBridge.

I've setup the following event monitors:

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.glue"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Glue Job State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "jobName": [
      "job-name-here"
    ],
    "state": [
      "SUCCEEDED",
      "FAILED"
    ]
  }
}
```

and

```
{
  "source": [
    "aws.glue"
  ],
  "detail-type": [
    "Glue Crawler State Change"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "crawlerName": [
      "crawler-name-here"
    ],
    "state": [
      "Succeeded",
      "Failed"
    ]
  }
}
```

Is there a similar way to do this with Lambda? I've had no success thus far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default no events from Lambda service other than Cloudtrail events are published to EventBridge, note that Lambda service is
not in this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-service-event.html

To publish events from success or failures of Lambdas you should instead configure your Lambda destination to publish it's success or failure event to the Eventbridge: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/